# setBreakpoint() function in R

Tags: r, debugging

Can we jump from one breakpoint to another within a function by using setBreakpoint() function twice and using "c" command?

Suppose the code is saved to a file named "test.R"

```
test1 <- function(x, y) {
  fit1 <- lm(y ~ x)
  fit2 <- lm(y ~ x)
  fit3 <- lm(y ~ x)
  fit7 <- lm(y ~ x)
  fit8 <- lm(y ~ x)
  fit9 <- lm(y ~ x)
  fit10 <- lm(y ~ x)
  invisible(list(beta = coef(fit1), yhat = fitted(fit1), res = residuals(fit1)))
}

setBreakpoint("test.R", 2)
test1(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```

After typing "n" ones in the broswer prompt then I typed

```
setBreakpoint("test.R", 5)
```

So I have set up another breakpoint at line 5. If I hit "c" it won't stop at this breakpoint, it will terminate the function.

Is there a way to invoke another breakpoint at a later stage while you are in the browser prompt? This works fine if the 2nd breakpoint is in another function. But if it is within the same function it won't.

Comment: @jogo It comes with `utils` package.

Comment: @jogo It was a mistake. Thanks, I have corrected it.